# yet another blank page in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, expressionengine

Please be gentle with me as I've never used CI or EE before! Long term I'll probably rewrite the site in something I'm a bit more familiar with but I need to get it working as is for now.

I've taken on a site for someone who has fallen out with his old IT guy/host/webdesigner and I'm trying to move his site over to a new server. I don't know a huge amount about his old server other than I believe it's on centos with plesk, the new server is ubuntu 12.04 with virtualmin and has slightly newer versions of php5 and mysql.

The site consists of CI with an expressionengine app with minimee installed.

I've got the control panel working just fine however much of the rest of the site just gives me a blank page.

Here's what I've done:

- copied all the files over and put the new db details in config/database.php
- replaced all the references to the old system path in the db dump with the new path with sed then imported it.
- changed the cache_path in minimee settings
- updated config/config.php with the new path
- set the debug to 1 in index.php
- error logging threshold to 4 in config.php (requests for blank pages end with "XSS Filtering completed" repeated four times).
- phpinfo shows show_errors is on.
- nothing shows up in the apache error logs.

NB: this only seems to affects some pages, if I directly request other pages then they display as expected.

Here's the template for one of the pages that isn't rendering:

```
{embed="embeds/index" 
title="{exp:query sql="SELECT cat_name FROM exp_categories WHERE cat_url_title = '{segment_2}' "}{cat_name}{if no_results}Equipment{/if}{/exp:query}"
}


    <div class="block-quarter">
        <h2>
            <a href="/{segment_1}" class="icon {segment_1}" title="{segment_1}">{segment_1}
            </a>
        </h2>
    {embed="embeds/category-nav" channel="equipment" path="info" group_id="2"}      
    </div>
    <div class="block-3quarter content">    
        <ul class="content-header">
            <li class="first">
                <a href="/equipment" title="Equipment">Equipment</a>        
                {if '{segment_2}' != ''}
                {exp:query sql="SELECT cat_name FROM exp_categories WHERE cat_url_title = '{segment_2}' "}
                {if no_results}{/if}&gt;
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/equipment/{segment_2}" title="">{cat_name}
                </a>
                {/exp:query}
                {/if}
            </li>
        </ul>
            {exp:query sql="SELECT cat_id FROM exp_categories WHERE cat_url_title = '{segment_2}' "}    
            {embed="embeds/list-equipment" cat_id="{cat_id}"}
                {if no_results}
                    {embed="embeds/list-equipment"}
                {/if}
            {/exp:query}

    </div>


{embed="embeds/footer"}
```

Anyone got any suggestions?

My feeling is that I've missed an reference to the old system path somewhere but for the life of me I can't see where. I've grep'ed the database dump I'm using and searched all the files that make up the site and found nothing.

EDIT:
Just thought I should add a template for a page that does render

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="company" disable="member_data|pagination" dynamic="yes" cache="yes" limit="1"}
{if no_results}{redirect="company"}{/if}

{embed="embeds/index" 
title="{title} {if segment_2} | Company{/if}" 
description="{exp:eehive_hacksaw words="25"}{page_content}{/exp:eehive_hacksaw}"}


    <div class="block-quarter">
        <h2>
            <a href="/{segment_1}" class="icon {segment_1}" title="{segment_1}">{segment_1}
            </a>
        </h2>
    {embed="embeds/side-nav" entry_id="12" title="Company" channel="company"}       
    </div>
    <div class="block-3quarter content">        

    {embed="embeds/breadcrumbs"}
    {image-placement}

    <h3>{title}</h3>
    <div id="content">
        {page_content}
    </div>
</div><!-- END Content -->

{embed="embeds/footer"}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

EDIT2:
here's the end of the CI log for a blank page:

```
DEBUG - 2013-08-05 19:07:56 --> Api class already loaded. Second attempt ignored.
DEBUG - 2013-08-05 19:07:56 --> Api_channel_fields class already loaded. Second attempt ignored.
DEBUG - 2013-08-05 19:07:56 --> Typography class already loaded. Second attempt ignored.
DEBUG - 2013-08-05 19:07:56 --> XSS Filtering completed
DEBUG - 2013-08-05 19:07:56 --> XSS Filtering completed
DEBUG - 2013-08-05 19:07:56 --> XSS Filtering completed
DEBUG - 2013-08-05 19:07:56 --> XSS Filtering completed
```

Comment: What's the error reporting level set to?

Comment: with debug=1 in index.php it looks like it's setting E_ALL

Comment: Do you have gzip compression enabled in `config.php`? If so try turning it off.

Comment: just tried turning it off, made no difference... thanks for the help guys

Comment: Is there anything informative in the CI log files?

Comment: "XSS Filtering completed" repeated four times when a page the doesn't render is requested.

Comment: SOLVED: I was missing gd on the server. I'll add an answer as soon as the question is over 8 hours old

Answer (score 1):

sorry guys I feel like a complete tool

I'd forgotten to make sure gd was installed.

Now it's installed everything works. I suppose I was right in thinking it was something simple, I was just wrong about what simple thing was causing the problem!

Thanks for the help everyone!